# Google Search Engine Two Page Layout Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine, google-custom-search

I've added a search engine in my site using the google's custom search engine. I chose the two page layout because what I want is that the search box will be at the home page and its result will be shown in another page. But it won't work on mine. Whenever I try to search something it won't show results and it won't go to the page. What can I do? Please help me. Thank you.

for search box

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

for results

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your pasted code indicating where the search result page is supposed to be.  Documented [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element).  Try adding that bit to your searchbox-only tag, e.g.:

```
<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="my-desired-search-results-landing-page"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```